# How to write a number as text while writing in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

```
import csv
a = ['679L', 'Z60', '033U', '0003']
z = csv.writer(open("test1.csv", "wb"))
z.writerow(a)
```

Consider the code above

Output:

```
676L   Z60   33U   3
```

I need to get it in the text format itself as

```
676L   Z60   033U   0003
```

How to do that.

Comment: The output for the code you posted is already what you expect. What tool are you using to *open* the CSV file with?

Comment: I'm getting output as 676L   Z60   33U   3 :(

Comment: But that is *not Python doing that*. Python writes `0003`.

Comment: Open the csv file in a text editor to see its actual contents.

Comment: I'm not using any other tool.

Comment: @NAVEEDALFARHAN: yet your output is not showing any commas. How did you check what output was produced?

Comment: @NAVEEDALFARHAN: I can reproduce the issue with Excel. Excel *is another tool here*.

Answer (score 4):

The Python `csv` module does **not** treat strings as numbers when writing the file:

```
>>> import csv
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> a = ['679L', 'Z60', '033U', '0003']
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> z = csv.writer(out)
>>> z.writerow(a)
>>> out.getvalue()
'679L,Z60,033U,0003\r\n'
```

If you are seeing `3` in some other tool *when reading* you need to fix that tool; Python is not at fault here.

You can instruct the `csv.writer()` to put quotes around anything that is not a number; this *could* make it clearer to whatever reads your CSV that the column is not numeric. Set `quoting` to [`csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC):

```
>>> out = StringIO()
>>> z = csv.writer(out, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
>>> z.writerow(a)
>>> out.getvalue()
'"679L","Z60","033U","0003"\r\n'
```

but this won't prevent Excel from treating the column as numeric *anyway*.

If you are loading this into Excel then don't use the *Open* feature. Instead create a new empty worksheet and use the *Import* feature instead. This will let you designate a column as *Text* rather than *General*.